# AWS CodeDeploy Service Fails on GitHub during Auto Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

When setting up automatic GitHub-triggered deployment as per [these instructions on the AWS blog](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx33XKAKURCCW83/Automatically-Deploy-from-GitHub-Using-AWS-CodeDeploy) I ran into a problem that's been very difficult to diagnose. When I push to my GitHub repo the GitHub Auto-Deployment service runs fine, but AWS CodeDeploy service fails with seemingly no information other than this bit of text when I hover over the error icon: "Last delivery was not successful. An exception occurred."

I've been trying to find a way to get any logs from GitHub's failed service run to get any kind of information about what kind of exception it actually ran into, but unless I'm blind there seems to be nothing. The setup as far as I can see is identical to the AWS blog post. Deploying manually through CodeDeploy using the GitHub repo works perfectly fine.

I'm wondering if anyone else has run into this when setting this up and figured out what happened (or can point me in the right direction)?

Comment: I contacted GitHub support and they were able to help very quickly.  When configuring the 'Environments' field during the  GitHub Auto-Deployment service hook configuration, the value specified MUST match the 'Deployment Group' value specified in the AWS CodeDeploy service hook.  My IAM setup was correct and this is what fixed the issue for me so I thought I should share.

Comment: This was really helpful for me. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

The issue with webhooks has since been fixed by GitHub.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

In addition to @jkovba 's comment regarding the 'Environments' parameter, the deployment group name as it's configured in AWS must be all lower case. For whatever reason, the GitHub webhooks downcases the deployment group name, causing a string mismatch when the request is processed by AWS (if your deployment group contains any upper case letters).

Use all lower case deployment group names in both the AWS configuration and the GitHub webservice/hook configuration.

Comment: Maybe its changed, but this is not the case for me. Uppercase first letter worked just fine.

Comment: I've been using upper-case "Staging" everywhere. No issues.